# How to tell a coworker something they did is not okay?

Tags: communication, manager

This is no longer an issue but for future reference what is the best way to tell something a coworker did is not okay without making them feel intimidated?

For context, we were working on a project and there were some things that came up that were clearly not finished on their end. We were behind schedule and they mention that they are going to go home. I work in a pretty "chill" workplace but the expectation is we get our things done but I did not want to say "hey we still have a lot of work to do, you can't leave yet."

They ended up getting their work done the next day and luckily we still managed to get everything done on time but it definitely was not something I thought was okay. Is it better to talk to them personally about it or is it something I should go to the manager about? The only reason I am hesitant to go to my manager about it is that I feel it's important I am communicating with my coworker and not just running to my manager whenever something is wrong.

EDIT: Seems like there are lots of factors that matter. I apologize for not addressing them.

In terms of there not being a problem, yes it ended up working out and everything got done but this did end up making people in QA have to wait another day giving them less time to work which made them work over the weekend. You can consider that a problem if you want. The bigger issue was when we both came together to talk about what we had to turn in for QA and things were definitely missing and when asked why they were not done and said that they completely forgot.

I am not a supervisor over this person but, at least at the time, I was definitely "leading" the project on our end. By that I mean people were coming to me to see when things were done, I was doing the hand off, etc. It's hard for me to say I was their supervisor but I am a tad more senior in the team of only us two...

In terms of the "chill" environment, it's a startup so some people work 40 hours, some people work 50 hours, some people clock in late and leave early. It really doesn't matter as long as you get your stuff done.

Comment: Are you in some kind of team leadership, supervisory or mentoring role over this person?

Comment: By the way, "he/she" is somewhat inappropriate from your point of view, since you know exactly who is involved.

Comment: Since it worked out, is it possible they were right to go home, relax and recharge? Are you more attached to the team getting the work done, or more attached to this person conforming to your preferred image of "busy"?

Comment: No, your workplace may be pretty cool, but it's not pretty "chill". As a non-manager, a pretty "chill" workplace would imply you would put in your 40 hours a week and that's it. In any case, I don't see what's wrong with saying "hey we still have a lot of work to do, you can't leave yet." Waiting for a better way of saying it is not going to make it any easier. If anything, waiting is only going to make the issue more important in the long-run than it really is.

Comment: "He/she ended up getting his/her work done the next day and luckily we still managed to get everything done on time" - So then was there actually a problem, or just the perception of a problem because a coworker's approach to working differs from yours?  Seems like the only thing that's "wrong" is that you personally dislike their working style.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments -- I updated the question to address some of the missing pieces. What you all brought up made sense.

Comment: Unless someone is slacking off at work or not working their full hours, things not getting done on time isn't a "Going home on time" problem, it's a project management problem.

Comment: Another thing to consider is the nature of the deadline, is it an external customer deliverable, or is it merely a PMP's milestone? If the latter, it is really hard to get people motivated for a symbolic or arbitrary deadline and short slips are totally understandable. Some highly effective workers are going to try to assess "the big picture" and plan accordingly rather than just do strictly what they're told to hit one of many deadlines.

Comment: I think this question is too broad and should be rewritten so that it more accurately reflects what the OP intends to ask. 'How to tell a coworker something they did is not OK' is not the same as, 'how to discuss priorities and project management with coworkers'. The title could be related to an offensive joke or action, whereas this question is specifically about someone's opinion about a co-worker leaving early.

Comment: @aroth: If the "personal dislike" of the working style is such that the OP feels overly (and, in their own planning, unnecessarily) stressed (in particular, if they had to wait for something the colleague had to do, and thus ended up doing it in the last minute), the issue might still be worth talking about. However, it needs to be clarified whether the *result* of the work was erroneous, or whether the *scheduling* of the work was suboptimal. The edit in the question suggests to me that actually *both* factors may be relevant here.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I tend to somewhat disagree with the first part.  The OP's feelings aren't really the coworker's responsibility.  The coworker's responsibility is to complete their work, which it sounds like they did.  And the OP's responsibility is the same.  In my opinion if you let someone else's working bother you so severely that you cannot get your own work done, the problem is yours unless they're doing something egregiously wrong (bullying, intimidating, deliberately distracting, etc.).  Successfully completing work without staying late doesn't qualify, IMO.

Comment: @aroth: I was referring to work that is linked in some way, i.e. one person waiting for another one to finish working on some artifact. As it seems to be the case here, given that QA has to wait for the coworker to finish before they can become active. (And irrespective of that, I consider behaving in a way that ignores the fact one's coworkers might be stressed as a direct result of one's behaviour as rather antisocial and inacceptable for working in a team.)

Comment: This makes no sense, they got it done on time? But this made people have to work over the weekend? That sounds like a terrible scheduling error. If you wanted it done a day earlier, the schedule should have been set a day earlier.

Comment: @marsh The date of launch was set for a specific date. We were scheduled to deliver final things to QA for testing by a specific date. We failed to meet the day to deliver to QA but were able to meet the date of launch (thankfully not many bugs). When I say "they got it done on time" I mean they got it done in time for launch and luckily QA reported very few errors. I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Everyday you are employed you will go home with unfinished work.  If the job is totally done, then you by definition no longer have a job to do.

So, the question is always when is the best point to get up and go home. But that is between your coworker and your boss, not you.

**When should you get involved, and ask your coworker to stay**?  When there is a specific task that only your co-worker can do, and this task can be done in a set amount of time that it is not unreasonable to expect them to stay over to do and you or your team are blocked until the task is completed.  And even then, you ask if they can stay, you don't tell them they can't leave.

**When should you complain about fit or lack of commitment**?  Most likely never, but if you feel you must, first identify a pattern of behavior, not a single instance.  Overtime, with or without pay, is just that -- time over the normal time.  As it is pushing into their time more than normal, there will be more conflicts, where overtime will just have to take a back seat to other priorities.  Even when a project is behind schedule,  a single instance should be unexceptional.

On a more practical note: your co-worker finished this the next day, but you say that others had to work over a weekend to get the project done on time.  Given both statements, it is unlikely that your coworker staying and working longer would have had a significant positive impact on the schedule, even if they were a bottleneck.  Given that fatigue breeds errors, I find it impossible to believe both (a) that it could have taken very long to get it done the next day and (b) that it could have been done in a reasonable amount of time the night before.  For anytime it took to do the next day, you can reasonably have expected it to have taken twice that the night before.  An hour or two the next day is not going to cause someone else to work over the weekend, and if it took all day, there's a good chance that staying later would have just resulted in bad work that needed to be redone, further putting the project behind schedule.

Comment: I liked the "even if your coworker had stayed, it probably wouldn't have made a difference."

Comment: It would make sense that an hour or two the next day could delay QA by a day, if QA are on a different schedule (unlikely unless they're on another continent) or if they're pulling an all-nighter themselves the day in question. In which case the error was made some days earlier: this project was running too close to the wire. It might be worth raising with management, that someone messed up the schedule to the extent that one person's ability to stay late on a particular night knocked on to an entire team working at the weekend.

Comment: ... if the workplace is "chill", then perhaps the questioner's colleague sees no reason why they should miss their weekly book group. or work long into the night at minimal productivity, just because the manager figured, "ah, I can be chilled about this schedule, people will just work overtime to fix my mistakes" ;-) It takes discipline and preparation to be relaxed *and* deliver on time.

Comment: Just reading the first line made me give you a +1. :)

Comment: This seems like a great answer. Thanks. And I appreciate all the comments - I don't mean for it to come off the wrong way. And I agree on many of the points you mentioned. I agree the schedule was messed up and we were already pressed for time as it is but we were made aware of it. And @JoeStrazzere thats very true thanks for adding that comment.

Answer (score 18):

Based upon your updates, I think the only real problem here is this:

> The bigger issue was when we both came together to talk about what we
>   had to turn in for QA and **things were definitely missing and when
>   asked why they were not done he/she said that he/she completely
>   forgot**.

Which is really not an issue of culture, or work-ethic/style.  It sounds like a process issue, to be honest (unless the coworker has a chronic problem with "forgotten" work?).  Whatever solution you're using for allocating and tracking work sounds like it's leaving too much up to individual human memories.  That's generally a recipe for...exactly that kind of situation.

Yes your co-worker dropped the ball by forgetting their tasks, but why does your process allow the ball to be dropped in such an impactful way in the first place?

If you're not currently using something like Trello or Jira Agile or a nice low-tech whiteboard with sticky-notes on it to track what tasks are assigned to whom and what the status of each one is, then I'd strongly suggest giving that a try.  At a minimum it takes away everyone's ability to hide behind the "I forgot" excuse (and can introduce a host of other benefits, as well).

As a senior member of the development team, you likely do hold significant influence over the development process being used, and it would be appropriate for you to raise the issue (in a general sense, like "we have a problem with people forgetting what tasks have been assigned to them") and advocate changes to the process to fix it.  I think that's your answer.

As for the rest, it sounds like what your coworker did in terms of not staying late to complete the tasks is actually in-line with your organization's culture:

> [...] some people work 40 hours, some people work 50 hours, some
>   people clock in late and leave early. **It really doesn't matter as long
>   as you get your stuff done**.

Your coworker did get the work done.  They shouldn't have forgotten to do it to begin with, but it sounds like once it was brought to their attention they dealt with it quickly and effectively (i.e. the very next day).

Your perception is that wasn't fast enough, but as their coworker and not their manager it's not really your call to make.  You may not know what they've worked out with their actual manager about the issue or more generally about working extra hours or their work-life balance.

In any case, the coworker's handling of the situation seems to be in line with the organization's culture/expectations.  If it really irks you, then start by advocating for a more formal culture.  Barring that, you're not their manager and senior or not you don't really get to have a direct say in terms of where, when, or how they do their work.  Those aren't things you can control in this situation.

What you can control is how you perceive and react to things your coworker does.  In that light I'd recommend looking at this as a "no harm, no foul" kind of situation.  I know you feel that a day of QA time was lost, but is that really the case?  Was the QA team just sitting there idle, waiting for your coworker to wrap up their forgotten tasks at 10:00 pm (or whenever)?  Would they really have started testing right that moment, and tested through the night?  Was there nothing else they could test in the meantime?

My general experience is that there's little practical difference between completing a task late at night and completing it during business hours the next day, apart from the cost to the employee's well-being.  So my suggestion would be to take this as an opportunity to improve your working processes to make it harder for people to just plain forget what things they're supposed to do, and leave it at that.

Answer (score 10):

### Perhaps it's worth considering this the other way around.

If the person knew that they had absolutely no chance to get the work done that day, then it would have served no purpose to pull an all-nighter to do it.  Also, perhaps they felt that if they tackled it afresh the next day then they would be able to get it done while not tired and likely to make mistakes.

### Did the person do wrong?

Well, yes.  If they did not adequately communicate the reasoning for their going home to the manager and the rest of the team when they were behind schedule, then they made a mistake.  Most good managers would recognise when a team member is trying to be *more* productive, not less so.  But without the critical piece of information, then you were all left wondering

### What should you do?

Well, as the other answers suggest, talk to them!  But not as a "You did wrong", but rather "What are your reasons for leaving this now?"  You don't need to be combative, it's more about understanding how different people work.

Of course, if you get an answer of "I couldn't have been bothered", then you have grounds to raise it with your manager as a potential risk.  You made your deadline this time (perhaps by the person recognising the best way for *them* to work, perhaps by luck), but if there is a pattern without explanation then it absolutely should be brought to the attention of those who manage the project's risk and deadlines.

Comment: I think much of the second section is speculative, and possibly even at odds with the OP.  We know that 1) the project was behind schedule _overall_, 2) some of the coworker's stuff wasn't finished, 3) the coworker's stuff did get finished, and 4) the project did complete on time.  Not specified is whether or not the coworker's features were themselves behind schedule, or their relevance to the overall project status.  Besides, since when is it reasonable to expect an employee to explain _why_ they're going home at the end of the day?  They don't live at work.

Comment: @aroth `I work in a pretty "chill" workplace but the expectation is we get our things done`  This is pretty indicative of "work until you're done" mentality.  Personally I disagree with it as it shows a lack of planning and management.  This is why my second section is saying what they did wrong was _not_ to go home, but why they went home with unfinished tasks, which seems at odds with the organisation's culture.  Otherwise the OP would not have posted the question in the first place :)

Comment: It could also be describing a "work however you want, as long as you get things done" mentality.  I have a hard time picturing a "work until you have no unfinished tasks _each day_" culture, as it would take an absurd amount of micromanagement (each employee needs formal tasks individually mapped to each working day) and be completely unsuited to development projects (where unfinished tasks at the end of the day is the norm).  There's not really enough info to decide either way.  We don't even know for a fact that the coworker _didn't_ discuss this with their manager (who's not the OP).

Comment: @aroth Your last comment I actually forgot to include in my answer about if the manager already knew.  Agreed we don't have all the information, unless the OP actually asks, neither do they.

Comment: `"If they did not adequately communicate the reasoning for their going home to the manager and the rest of the team when they were behind schedule, then they made a mistake."` --> Not being paid to work overtime is a reason that doesn't need to be comunicated to any manager. Surelly the manager knows the empoyees' paycheck and schedules. So, no, the co-worker didn't do anything wrong. It was his/her absolute right to leave, if it was past the time to leave.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel See my previous comment to aroth.  I completely agree with you, but the OP indicates a culture of "stay until it's done".  _Given this culture_, then the person should indeed have stated that they were not going to follow this culture, and instead finish the job the next day.

Comment: @JaneS Culture doesn't pay your bills. Besides, people have families, apointments, cats to take care of, other things to do than working extra-time for free.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Again, I agree.  But, you are missing a pretty major point. _Would the OP have asked this question had it been "normal" for people in that organisation just to go home at the end of the day like they are entitled to do?_  The OP also mentions some people do 40 hours, some do 50 hours.  This to me is a huge red flag that the organisation has issues with work/life balance and expectations of employees.  But the OP asked the question, because clearly they think the person _should_ have stayed late.  It's this that needs addressing.

Comment: @JaneS I still think the person shouldn't have stayed longer. Unless the work could be done in a very short time without interfeering with said person's life.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel If you read my answer carefully, you'll see that I'm saying exactly the same thing ;)

Comment: @JaneS I re-re-re-read it, and still can't find it. Could you please quote it? (Maybe I should take a nap instead)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `Most good managers would recognise when a team member is trying to be more productive (by going home), not less so. But without the critical piece of information, then you were all left wondering` I added the bracketed bit to the quote as that was what thought was implied :)

Comment: @JaneS That part is implied, and I got it. But when you say that you addressed all those points you mean the part that says `"[...] Without the critical piece of information [...]"?`

Comment: In general I'd agree with you @Jane. However, in certain circumstances I can imagine working a few more hours to get the software off to QA and meet an important deadline, and make a customer happy, is acceptable. When it becomes the norm, this is of course not acceptable.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra That was kind of my point :)  If the OP's colleague felt that it wasn't possible to achieve that day, then it was reasonable to go home and complete it the next day.  This is, of course, in the context of an organisation that expects people to stay late to finish tasks.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I mean that unless the OP's colleague says _why_ they went home instead of finishing the task, then it's pure speculation that it was laziness or any other reason.  My answer is merely pointing out that they shouldn't assume that but rather there may be a very _professional_ reason for completing the job next day.

Comment: The problem is that there is always *something* important to do, which could be used as a reason to work overtime.  We can't all work 16 hours per day every single day.  We need to draw the line.  If this co-worker had a commitment after work and knew they could perform this work the next day without affecting the schedule, and they did, bravo for them.  There is a time and place for over-time.

Answer (score 3):

I would speak to the coworker first, especially if it's a team effort and they're not pulling their weight. There is no need to intimidate them, a polite request would be fine rather than a demand. Something like:
We need to get this done by tomorrow, are you ok? Do you have a plan? Need some help?
(I find that asking people if they need help disarms any offence they might otherwise take)

If it continually impacts on your work and stresses you then two things need to be looked at depending which you think applies.

Your working relationship with your coworker. Communication can be an issue which many people make no effort with, it is always best to cultivate good communication with anyone you work with, its the basis of a good team which benefits all concerned.

Your coworkers work habits, if they impact on your ability to perform then they may well be something to take up with management. It's not productive to worry about others feelings if they jeapardise your own work and deadlines.

At the end of the day you don't want management to judge you based on someone elses work practices

Comment: I would add that the expectation of overtime (or staying until it's done) should be set ahead of time whenever possible. Folks need to be able to make arrangements, and lead time is always appreciated. Coworkers need to understand, too, that people have diverse lives and work after 5pm may have to take a backseat. In today's world, where a lot of work can be done remotely, we can work around folks' needs.

Comment: I really like the advice to offer help -- I think I could have suggested something like that and that would have made things a lot clearer and also seem less aggressive.

Comment: it's a disarming way of doing it, it's much less confrontational, I use it a lot. Not because I actually want to help, but because it comes across much better.

Answer (score 2):

Always best to start closest to the problem. Talk to the co-worker -- managers most of the time want you to solve your own problems when you can. In this case it doesn't sound like you plan to talk to the co-worker since everything worked out.

If this situation arises in the future, then when having the discussion, stick to facts. Start with something positive (and true), to make clear that you are not just looking for problems, along the lines of: *You've been doing great work in the last few weeks,* or *Thanks for all of your effort so far on this project.*

In terms of the project or problem, again stick to facts: The project is due on X date. Your part of the project must be done by X. It must include completion of tasks X, Y, and Z.

Then you can say: do you think you can still go home and meet these obligations? How? What's your plan for doing so? What if something unexpected comes up? Do you have a contingency?

You're giving the other person flexibility, and the freedom to make choices, while still emphasizing responsibility and execution.

Comment: This is especially appropriate if you have some sort of leadership role with respect to the person (eg, team lead, mentor, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Remarking on someone's work habits is strictly the prerogative of their direct supervisor, whoever their hiring manager is. It would be out of place for you to talk to them directly about it. If the person's supervisor found out you had done such a thing, they would not be happy about it.

If you are unhappy about it, complain to YOUR boss, then it will go up the chain and back down again until it reaches the other person's supervisor. That is the proper channel.

Be aware that some people, especially those with families, consider their work and family hours to be strictly segregated and if they decide "I go home to be with my family at 5pm," then that is what they do. Trying to infringe on this time boundary can have serious organizational consequences.